# Use same texture from the other object beneath target object

Tags: materials, shaders

For example, there are two plane.
[image]
Plane A is the beneath one with ABXY texture.
Plane B is the upper one which is selected (show the green outline) and it's a decal mesh.

And I want no matter where plane B move. Plane B always get the projection of plane A as its texture. There's diagrammatic image below.
[image]
Plane B get the Y corner texture part as its texture.

What's the purpose? If the decal mesh is just for a addition normal. There's no method to get transparent+normal work together. So, I think get the same texture zone beneath it is the way out.

Comment: The UVProject modifier should work well in a simple scene as your example.

Comment: What do you mean by saying there's no method to get transparent+normal work together?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann
There's no way to use transparent base color with normal map right? unlike those powerful shader in game engine. For example: [UE4 Decal Blend Mode](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/Resources/ContentExamples/Decals/1_2/)

Comment: @Secrop
I think you misunderstand what kind of effect I want to reach.

Comment: @OkazakiNaoki To understand it correctly, you want something like a decal with transparent areas placed over some other texture... and the decal should have some bump through a normal map. In the transparent areas or the opaque areas? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer since I'm not sure if I completely understand your problem. Let's say you have a decal as PNG with transparency like this (the white part is actually transparent, unfortunately not visible here):

[image: decal]

And the normal map looks like this, so that the blue bars and the text is raised (note that the raised part extend the opaque part of the decal):

[image: normal map]

You want to place the decal on some plane which has a different texture like this example:

[image: plane without decal]

So that it looks like this (sorry the image maps are very low resolution):

[image: plane with decal]

To achieve something like that I would use a node setup like this:

[image: decal node setup]

You can mix the decal over the base texture by using its *Alpha Channel*. The *Normal Map* node can simply be put into the *Normal Input* of a *Principled BSDF* node.

If you set the *Image Texture* nodes containing the decal image and the normal map to *Interpolation* > *Extend* instead of the default *Repeat*, you can move the decal around and scale it with a *Mapping* node.

If you want the decal to be not fully opaque in the image's opaque areas, you can use a *Map Range* node like I did in the example setup or maybe a *Color Ramp*. Decreasing the *To Max* value (or setting the ramp's bright value to some grey instead of white) will make the decal more transparent.

To move and scale the decal with a control plane you can use the *Object* output of the *Texture Coordinate* node and select the control plane as reference object like in the following example (but for more complex meshes the first version with *UV* might work better):

[image]

Comment: but in my case there's only decal normal map, no base color image for decal.

Comment: Then don't mix in a base color, just plug in the normal map...? But where do you have transparency, in the normal map? A normal map usually has no transparency.

Comment: I guess I completely misunderstand what you're trying to do so my answer is useless...

Comment: Maybe you can see the example on UE4. [example](https://i.imgur.com/uEEPokF.png)

Comment: decal base color is simply transparent. and "only" normal map on decal mesh. it's like a normal only decal for adding normal by decal method.

Comment: @OkazakiNaoki, there isn't this functionality in Blender. There are plenty of tools that would let you accomplish that, But you still have to differenciate bettween UV projections, and texture mixings. They (and your question also!) are two problems alone on their own.. one works on a mesh level, and  the other on a material level (a mesh can have multiple materials, and a material can be in multiple meshes).

Comment: @OkazakiNaoki Well, with my method - if you do it within the same material - then you simply just plug in a normal map as I said before. You can move, scale and rotate it with texture coordinates. If you would an extra material with a simple _Transparent BSDF_ the problem would be, it's only transparent - it has no glossiness or anything, so a bump created by a normal map would be invisible. You need the surface qualities of the underlying material to be effected by the normal map - and in this case you can add it in the material like i did. But it won't be a real decal.

Comment: yea, your method is like decal machine addon